# how to work with .each() inside a onclick event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following situation and I don't understand why it is not working. I have several `<input>` fields in a table and each time that the user clicks in one of the inputs I check if this element is already in the list of inputs of this table, if not I just add it. The official addition to the list of inputs is when the user clicks at least one time in the `<input>` element. I do this like this:

```
var element_input =  {"Element": ""};
var input_element = [];


$("#input"+i).click(function(){
       element_input.Element =  $(this);
       var found = false;               
       $.each(input_element,function(i){
            if(input_element[i].Element === $(this))
               input_element.splice(i,1,element_input);
               found = true;
       });
       if(!found){
         input_element.push(element_input);
       }
  });
```

But this is absolutely not working! I don't know what is wrong there. He insert the first element in the list because is empty, that means is going till the end of the code and in the same iteration is going again to the .each loop, like if I made again click in the element and he should start to read the code again, and of course he add this element because the condition is true. In the end I have an infinite list with the same element several times. Can somebody help me?
THX!!

Comment: That's just really friggin confusing? Why not just `input_element.indexOf(this)`, and why an object with just one property that makes no sense ?

Comment: Use class instead of id when calling the .click function

Comment: Hi! @adeneo Thx for your answer. The object has more elements of course, but I just don't wanted to make a long story and I let the important element for me in this case

Comment: Why not just tell us why you need an array of inputs, you could probably just do something like `var inputs = $('.inputs').filter(something)` and be done with it,

Comment: I think adeneo is on the right track `input_element[i].Element === $(this)` will never be true because the element is not the same jQuery object. Any `$(this)` will not identical to the next one.

Comment: ^ and even if it was a jQuery object, two objects are never the same, you'd have to compare DOM nodes instead, and then `indexOf` would work

Comment: Exactly, I was just editing something similar to my comment.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/t4xcfp9y/1/

Comment: I tryed with the == operator and of course @adeneo was right, 2 objects are never the same. Also I compere the attr('id') of each one  (the element from the list and the current element) and I have the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, you have too many issues in your code, some of the parts are not clear for me. This peace of code:

```
  $.each(input_element,function(i){
        if(input_element[i].Element === $(this))
           input_element.splice(i,1,element_input);
           found = true;
   });
```

found always will be true, check brackets, also `input_element[i].Element === $(this)` is always false, because you are comparing two objects.

Here is you example written on better way. http://jsfiddle.net/ux6hhefe/2/

Comment: THX Grissom! Is exactly what I wanted! Wonderful!

Comment: I was compering the same object with hiself! This of course is wrong and I was swimming in a crazy loop!

Answer (score 1):

A more accurate solution could be is to use a class to denote the selected elements then when you need you can filter only those elements.

Also you can add a common class to all the input elements and use that to add the click handler.

```
$(".input").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});

//then when you need to get all the selected elements
var input_element = $('.input.selected');
//if you want input_element to be an array then use
var input_element = $('.input.selected').get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because by default equality operator checks that objects are equal by reference. In your case they always different, because each $() call returns new object.

You can check it by single line of code:

```
$(this)==$(this)
```

Try to use `this` instead of `$(this)`